# Get session value in struts/sitemesh

Tags: struts2, sitemesh

I'm using sitemesh with struts2. I want to create a login/logout link on the main layout page. How do we get the value of session there.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple example**

**`decorators.xml`**

```
<decorators defaultdir="/decorators">
    <decorator name="default" page="default.jsp">
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

---

**`/decorators/default.jsp`**

**With Struts2 Tag**

```
<s:set var="isNoLogin">${empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}</s:set>

<s:if test="#isNoLogin">
    <s:a action="login">Login</s:a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:a action="logout">Logout</s:a>
</s:else>
```

or

```
<s:set var="remoteUser">${pageContext.request.remoteUser}</s:set>

<s:if test="#remoteUser != null && !#remoteUser.isEmpty()">
    <s:a action="login">Login</s:a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:a action="logout">Logout</s:a>
</s:else>
```

---

**With JSTL**

```
<c:if test="${empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}">
    <s:a action="login">Login</s:a>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}">
    <s:a action="logout">Logout</s:a>
</c:if>
```

or

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}">
        <s:a action="login">Login</s:a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <s:a action="logout">Logout</s:a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: struts part

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /JSP/Decorators/Header.jsp at line 8
`code`
5:  Akrithi Paytime <span>- Billing and Payment Management System</span>
6: </h1>
7: <p>
8:     <s:set var="isNoLogin">${empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}</s:set>
9: 
10:     <s:if test="#isNoLogin">
11:         <s:a action="login">Login</s:a> `code`

Comment: @Akhil You should try yourself for this exception. What value of `${empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}`? Try in new blank .jsp page. Version of Struts2 & Tomcat/web server?

Comment: both latest version. struts and apache...

${empty pageContext.request.remoteUser} returning true.

Comment: What about in new, blank, no `Sitemesh-decorated` jsp page with only `<s:set var="isNoLogin">${empty pageContext.request.remoteUser}</s:set>`?